# Minimum wages in France

Tags: labor-economics, data, minimum-wage

Does somebody know where I can find historical data on minimum wages in France for different worker groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is available from 1980 to 2023 on the webpage of the national statistical institute INSEE:
https://www.insee.fr/fr/statistiques/1375188

In a centralized country like France, the minimum wage is "universal" in the sense that it applies to all workers (and is independent from the worker group, industry, gender, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I would say the best place to look would be the Ministry of Work/Labor, in French, Ministère du Travail. Also potentially the Ministry of Economy and Finance or Le Ministère de l'Économie et des Finances. You may also want to check the OECD website as they have extensive data on their member countries such as France.`